# I'm triying to find this box

Tags: html, css, select

http://postimg.org/image/oola4fxp5/

Hey my friends!
Please help me! I have to create this box for email field but i dont know what it's attiribute. How can i create this?

Comment: Hi there, normally on this site good questions are ones where you have demonstrated an attempt and are having troubles. This sort of question you asked can be answered with commonly available development tools, such as Google Chrome's Web Developer Tools.  If you're unfamiliar, I would suggest that as a great place to start your web development endeavours. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a textarea

`<textarea></textarea>`

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) for more information on attributes and such.